# Can quantum computing solve the curse of dimensionality?

Tags: quantum-information, computational-physics, quantum-computer, optimization

The [curse of dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality) is ubiquitous in [machine learning](https://www.newton.ac.uk/files/seminar/20080218163017001-151449.pdf) (ML) modeling, [stochastic control](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.04706) and [reinforcement learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.05866), arising in a probabilistic sense, with [strong connections to quantum mechanics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.06064).

Typical approaches in ML and controls  utilize *local* approximations, since the globally optimal solution requires solving a problem which scales exponentially with the number of data points or dimensionality of the problem.

Hypothetically, is it possible to use the fundamental connections between these phenomena (whether noisy data or stochastic processes, including quantum phenomena) to solve the problem (rather than re-fashioning classical algorithms to solve NP hard problems) via quantum computing?

Comment: This feels basically equivalent to the question "Does the addition of quantum algorithms make $P=NP$?" If so, the answer is basically that we don't know yet but that people generally don't expect the answer to be yes: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/73864/

Comment: @probably_someone, please allow me to elaborate. The curse of dimensionality problem arises in [ML modeling](https://www.newton.ac.uk/files/seminar/20080218163017001-151449.pdf), [stochastic control](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.04706) and [reinforcement learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.05866.pdf) in a probabilistic sense, with [strong connections to quantum mechanics](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.06064.pdf). The question pertains to the possibility of using these fundamental connections to solve the problem, rather than re-fashioning classical algorithms to solve NP hard problems.

Comment: Are you looking for something like quantum annealing (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_annealing)?

Comment: There is a quantum computing stackexchange, I think you will get much better answers there: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/